# Why does my Django form is_valid() return false?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I'm a bit stuck. Could somebody tell me why the `is_valid()` function returns false and also shows no errors on the screen? I've managed to simplify my view as much as possible, the `HttpResponseRedirect` is always redirecting to `/information` no matter what data I populate the form with.

**forms.py**

```
class FantasySeasonForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = FantasyTeam

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super(FantasySeasonForm,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        #filter all players to only premier league players
        self.fields['player1'].queryset = Player.objects.filter(team__competition__pk=2)
        self.fields['player2'].queryset = Player.objects.filter(team__competition__pk=2)
        self.fields['player3'].queryset = Player.objects.filter(team__competition__pk=2)
        self.fields['player4'].queryset = Player.objects.filter(team__competition__pk=2)
        self.fields['player5'].queryset = Player.objects.filter(team__competition__pk=2)
        self.fields['player6'].queryset = Player.objects.filter(team__competition__pk=2)
        self.fields['player7'].queryset = Player.objects.filter(team__competition__pk=2)
        self.fields['player8'].queryset = Player.objects.filter(team__competition__pk=2)
        self.fields['player9'].queryset = Player.objects.filter(team__competition__pk=2)
        self.fields['player10'].queryset = Player.objects.filter(team__competition__pk=2)
        self.fields['player11'].queryset = Player.objects.filter(team__competition__pk=2)
        self.fields['player12'].queryset = Player.objects.filter(team__competition__pk=2)
        self.fields['player13'].queryset = Player.objects.filter(team__competition__pk=2)
        self.fields['player14'].queryset = Player.objects.filter(team__competition__pk=2)
        self.fields['player15'].queryset = Player.objects.filter(team__competition__pk=2)
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def entry(request):    
    fantasyTeamForm = FantasySeasonForm() #Form to store each player in the fantasy team
    seasonUserTournForm = PartialSeasonEntryForm()

    # If the form has been submitted... 
    if request.method == 'POST':
        fantasyTeamForm = FantasySeasonForm(request.POST or None) # A form bound to the POST data

        if fantasyTeamForm.is_valid():                      
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/season/entrysuccess') #page on success

        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/information') #page on error

    #OTHERWISE A GET REQUEST
    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))

    args['form'] = fantasyTeamForm
    args['form2'] = seasonUserTournForm

    return render_to_response('entry.html', args, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**entry.html**

```
    <h2><b>Choose your team:</b></h2><br>

    {% for field in form %}
      {{field.error}}
    {% endfor %}
    {% for field in form2 %}
      {{field.error}}
    {% endfor %}

    <form action="/season/entry/" method="post"> {% csrf_token %}
      {{form2}}
      <br><br>
      {{form.as_ul}}
      <br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit Team" />         
    </form>
```

**Update**

After selected values for the team name and players 1-7, leaving the rest blank I have printed the following values in the else statement..

`form.is_bound` returns `True`

`form.errors` returns

`<ul class="errorlist"><li>player9<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>player4<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>player8<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>player11<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>player10<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>player5<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>player14<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>player6<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>player13<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>player3<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>player12<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>player15<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>player7<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>`

`form.data` returns

`<QueryDict: {'player14': [''], 'player9': [''], 'player4': ['3897'], 'team_name': ['Just Amazing'], 'player8': [''], 'player11': [''], 'player10': [''], 'player5': ['3897'], 'player1': ['1934'], 'player12': [''], 'player6': ['13017'], 'player13': [''], 'player2': ['1934'], 'player3': ['3897'], 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['H8dIdnepxSgEduPCT6Yiy9iYsLmXqwJy'], 'player15': [''], 'player7': ['13017']}>`

Comment: If you didn't redirect away from the view in the else clause, the form itself would show you its errors.

Comment: When it doesn't have an else clause, no errors are shown and the page just simply refreshes!

Comment: just do `print form.errors` in the `else` clause before the return statement. You would know what the errors are. Alternately, just comment out the entire else block for now - you will see what the exact errors are

Comment: I have tried `print form.errors` and I believe it is either Null or it is a blank string. Having no `else` statement also does nothing, which is why I included it in the first place

Comment: print `repr(form.errors)` if you think it's `None`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass `*args` and `**kwargs` when constructing your form.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(FantasySeasonForm,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    ...
```

By missing out `*args`, your current code has the same effect as if you did `fantasyTeamForm = FantasySeasonForm(data=None)`. Even though there are no errors, `is_valid()` returns `False` because the form is not bound to any data.

As an aside, you can loop through the player fields to avoid repetition:

```
for player_id in xrange(1, 16)
    field_name = "player%d" % player_id 
    self.fields[field_name].queryset = Player.objects.filter(team__competition__pk=2)
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, however still nothing changes. It's as if it doesn't attempt to validate the form at all, doesn't matter what values I give as players

Comment: If you have made the change I suggested and it's still now working, print `form.is_bound`, `form.errors` and `form.data` in the `else` block, and update your question with the results.

Comment: Think this was the problem afterall. It so happened that I also did something very odd with the urls.py so that it was returning what looked like the same page!